# How self.anchors is not self. declared in the __init__ but it's used in the method?

Tags: python, class, oop, pytorch, self

```
class Detect(nn.Module):
    stride = None  # strides computed during build
    onnx_dynamic = False  # ONNX export parameter
    export = False  # export mode

    def __init__(self, nc=80, anchors=(), ch=(), inplace=True):  # detection layer
        super().__init__()
        self.nc = nc  # number of classes
        self.no = nc + 5  # number of outputs per anchor
        self.nl = len(anchors)  # number of detection layers
        self.na = len(anchors[0]) // 2  # number of anchors
        self.grid = [torch.zeros(1)] * self.nl  # init grid
        self.anchor_grid = [torch.zeros(1)] * self.nl  # init anchor grid
        self.register_buffer('anchors', torch.tensor(anchors).float().view(self.nl, -1, 2))  # shape(nl,na,2)
        self.m = nn.ModuleList(nn.Conv2d(x, self.no * self.na, 1) for x in ch)  # output conv
        self.inplace = inplace  # use inplace ops (e.g. slice assignment)

    def _make_grid(self, nx=20, ny=20, i=0):
        d = self.anchors[i].device
        t = self.anchors[i].dtype

        shape = 1, self.na, ny, nx, 2  # grid shape
        y, x = torch.arange(ny, device=d, dtype=t), torch.arange(nx, device=d, dtype=t)
        if check_version(torch.__version__, '1.10.0'):  # torch>=1.10.0 meshgrid workaround for torch>=0.7 compatibility
            yv, xv = torch.meshgrid(y, x, indexing='ij')
        else:
            yv, xv = torch.meshgrid(y, x)
        grid = torch.stack((xv, yv), 2).expand(shape) - 0.5  # add grid offset, i.e. y = 2.0 * x - 0.5
        anchor_grid = (self.anchors[i] * self.stride[i]).view((1, self.na, 1, 1, 2)).expand(shape)
        return grid, anchor_grid
```

In the init there's no self.anchors = anchors but in the _make_grid() method they are using self.anchors. How is it possible?
PS I had to drop the forward method otherwise stackoverflow claimed there was too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this call in `__init__`:

```
self.register_buffer('anchors', torch.tensor(anchors).float().view(self.nl, -1, 2))  # shape(nl,na,2)
```

Let's see what [the PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) have to say about `nn.Module.register_buffer`:

> > `register_buffer(name, tensor, persistent=True)`
> > Adds a buffer to the module.
>
> This is typically used to register a buffer that should not to be
> considered a model parameter. For example, BatchNorm’s `running_mean` is
> not a parameter, but is part of the module’s state. Buffers, by
> default, are persistent and will be saved alongside parameters. This
> behavior can be changed by setting `persistent` to False. The only
> difference between a persistent buffer and a non-persistent buffer is
> that the latter will not be a part of this module’s `state_dict`.
>
> **Buffers can be accessed as attributes using given names.**
>
> > Parameters
> >
> > - `name` (`string`) – name of the buffer. The buffer can be
> >   accessed from this module using the given name
>
> [...]

So it appears the base class you're inheriting from exposes any registered buffer as an attribute, hence the availability of `self.anchors` at runtime

Comment: @AlessandroMondin Happy to help! Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)